# Override CSS site style with stylesheet on page

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Is there any way of overriding all other CSS on a page and applying a different stylesheet. I have a file with H1,H2,P tags specified in stylesheet but in a modal window I want to apply separate styles but the styles are being ignored in place of the site styles. Is there anyway of stopping the initial site styles being applied

Comment: No, you can't go back and remove what's already been applied, hence 'cascading' you'll just need to overwrite the styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to remove all stylesheet tags from the HEAD element of the page using JS, except the sheet you want (or then add in that sheet).

If you use jQuery,

`$('link[rel=stylesheet]').remove();`

Or to target specific sheets:

`$('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="whatever.css"]').remove();`

Though this, as noted by @Olly Hodgson would be overkill and destroy the styling you'd rely on for the page.

Realistically, place your preferred stylesheet below all others (and any inline CSS), it will override any rules not using the `!important` demarkation. Alternatively, if you are writing CSS and the specific style is not being enforced, use `!important`, eg:

```
   div{height:99px!important;}
```

Comment: Removing all the existing page styles while a modal is loaded seems like overkill. And what happens when the user closes the modal?

Comment: Horrible idea anyway but that was what was needed to do it thanks

Answer (score 1):

Write your new styles just below to the ones that you need to override. This will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another stylesheet to the page *after* any others already loaded. Then make sure the rules you write in it are of [a higher specicifity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) than the ones you wish to override.

So if your main page's CSS has something like this:

```
p { color: #000000; }
```

You could override it in your modal like this (assuming your modal has `class="modal"`):

```
.modal p { color: red; }
```

Another option is the load the modal content into an iframe, using a page which only has your styles supplied.